# Unable to install virtualbox on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: virtualbox

I do this by executing:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

here is the installatino output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgsoap-2.8.75 libqt5opengl5 libvncserver1 virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
  vde2 virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgsoap-2.8.75 libqt5opengl5 libvncserver1 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/46,8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 162 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Selecting previously unselected package libgsoap-2.8.75:amd64.
(Reading database ... 201554 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-libgsoap-2.8.75_2.8.75-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgsoap-2.8.75:amd64 (2.8.75-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libqt5opengl5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../1-libqt5opengl5_5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libvncserver1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../2-libvncserver1_0.9.11+dfsg-1.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.11+dfsg-1.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../3-virtualbox-dkms_6.0.6-dfsg-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (6.0.6-dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Preparing to unpack .../4-virtualbox_6.0.6-dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox (6.0.6-dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Preparing to unpack .../5-virtualbox-qt_6.0.6-dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (6.0.6-dfsg-1) ...
Setting up libvncserver1:amd64 (0.9.11+dfsg-1.3) ...
Setting up libgsoap-2.8.75:amd64 (2.8.75-1) ...
Setting up libqt5opengl5:amd64 (5.12.2+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.0.6-dfsg-1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-6.0.6 DKMS files...
Building for 5.0.0-38-generic
Building initial module for 5.0.0-38-generic
Done.

vboxdrv.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.0.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.0.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.0.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.0.0-38-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-13 01:14:36 MSK; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6428 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

feb 13 01:14:36 rm-pc systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
feb 13 01:14:36 rm-pc virtualbox[6428]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
feb 13 01:14:36 rm-pc virtualbox[6428]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
feb 13 01:14:36 rm-pc virtualbox[6428]:    ...fail!
feb 13 01:14:36 rm-pc systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
feb 13 01:14:36 rm-pc systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
feb 13 01:14:36 rm-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Setting up virtualbox (6.0.6-dfsg-1) ...
vboxweb.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
● virtualbox.service - LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/virtualbox; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-02-13 01:14:38 MSK; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 6647 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/virtualbox start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

feb 13 01:14:38 rm-pc systemd[1]: Starting LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module...
feb 13 01:14:38 rm-pc virtualbox[6647]:  * Loading VirtualBox kernel modules...
feb 13 01:14:38 rm-pc virtualbox[6647]:  * modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why
feb 13 01:14:38 rm-pc virtualbox[6647]:    ...fail!
feb 13 01:14:38 rm-pc systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
feb 13 01:14:38 rm-pc systemd[1]: virtualbox.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
feb 13 01:14:38 rm-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
Setting up virtualbox-qt (6.0.6-dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (240-6ubuntu5.8) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.10-1) ...
```

So , as far as I understand, the error is that it **failed to start LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.**

Virtualization on my laptop is enabled.

Comment: See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details. In a terminal type those two commands in "quotes". It appears to have been installed. You will need to read the logs to gather more information as to why the virtualbox.service is not starting. Post the details from the logs if you are still not able to determine why the service is not starting.

Comment: @da_kingpin I've just done that and except for the error I mentioned above in bold, there's this line: `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key`. I'm just clueless...

Comment: @da_kingpin I've tried running a newly created machine but it errors out with `The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the kernel module by executing

'modprobe vboxdrv'

as root.
`

Comment: @da_kingpin if I execute `sudo modprobe vboxdrv` I get `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxdrv': Operation not permitted`

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 uses kernel version 5.3, not 5.0 as indicated in your output. You seem to have an incomplete release-upgrade or some other kind of FrankenSystem. Fix that, and then you won't need to muck with SecureBoot.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I was finally able to resolve the issues with the help of the instructions that can be foud here.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=91160

Answer (score 0):

the problem stems form the fact there are some kernel modules that are not signed, thus making it impossible to load on a device
with *secure boot* settings active.

**these kernal modules  are the following
1- vboxnetadp
2- vboxnetflt
3- vboxdrv**

In order to sign them and instert them into the kernal  copy paste these commands in your terminal

for the first time , we will need to make a new folder to keep our workspace clean

cd ~
mkdir tempkeys
cd tempkeys

then we will do the following  ( replace MODULE_NAME in line 2 for each of the modules accordingly ) and restart after each
time that you sign a model

```
openssl req -new -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout MOK.priv -outform DER -out MOK.der -nodes -days 36500 -subj "/CN=Descriptive common name/"
sudo /usr/src/linux-headers-$(uname -r)/scripts/sign-file sha256 ./MOK.priv ./MOK.der $(modinfo -n MODULE_NAME)
tail $(modinfo -n vboxdrv) | grep "Module signature appended"
sudo mokutil --import MOK.der
```

and when you are done do not forget to reinstall virtualbox dmsk again by running

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r) virtualbox-dkms dkms
```

Comment: With WSL2 this doesn't work
`sudo mokutil --import MOK.der`

yields
`EFI variables are not supported on this system`